# Finding the slices from a list of coordinates in a numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to retrieve a list of slices from a list of coordinates in a multidimensional numpy.

What I am doing is the following (example).

First, I declare my base array:

```
base = np.zeros((8, 8, 4))
```

with a list of coordinates:

```
coord = [slice(0, 1, None), slice(0, None, None)]
```

Second, I create a "mask" in the numpy:

```
base[coord] = -1
```

Then, I extract the slices of that area:

```
np.argwhere(base == -1)
```

The problem I have is that I don't want to modificate the numpy in order to extract the coordinates, and of course a copy is not a possible solution. What's the way to do it or what modification I should do for obtaining the slices?

Comment: why don't you use `pandas`, `DataFrame`, it will allow for slicing, filtering, dicing etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
base = np.zeros((8, 8, 4))
coord = [slice(0, 1, None), slice(0, None, None)]
all_coords = np.argwhere(base == base).reshape(*base.shape,base.ndim)  # (8,8,4,3)
print(all_coords[coord].reshape(-1,base.ndim))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 2 1]
 [0 2 2]
 [0 2 3]
 [0 3 0]
 [0 3 1]
 [0 3 2]
 [0 3 3]
 [0 4 0]
 [0 4 1]
 [0 4 2]
 [0 4 3]
 [0 5 0]
 [0 5 1]
 [0 5 2]
 [0 5 3]
 [0 6 0]
 [0 6 1]
 [0 6 2]
 [0 6 3]
 [0 7 0]
 [0 7 1]
 [0 7 2]
 [0 7 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the array of coordinates with `np.meshgrid`, using ranges instead of slices:

```
import numpy as np

base = np.zeros((8, 8, 4))
coord = [range(0, 1), range(0, base.shape[1])]
coords_array = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*coord, indexing='ij'), -1).reshape(-1, len(coord))
print(coords_array)
# [[0 0]
#  [0 1]
#  [0 2]
#  [0 3]
#  [0 4]
#  [0 5]
#  [0 6]
#  [0 7]]
```